# Can I delete a parent snapshot?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vmware-tools

I am trying to maintain different builds of my code in different snapshots of the same virtual machine.
Right now, this is my current view in the snapshot manager (vsphere) for that particular VM:

```
[-]Base environment
 |__Version 1.1
 |__Version 2.0
    |__Version 2.1
```

Now I want to delete snapshot "Version 2.0" or promote 2.1 to the place where 2.0 exists.
I'd be happy if there was a way to merge 2.0 and 2.1 and retain changes from 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete any snapshot that you want. vSphere will merge the changes with the next snaphot - "Version 2.1" will take place of "Version 2.0". I did it before with vSphere client - there were no problems with that. It may take some time though, especially if there are many differences between the snapshots.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

No. Snapshots are incremental. In fact, if you crack them open with a hex editor you'll see they form a chain (independent of the file name).

You should have been using a source control system like Subversion or Git (there are many others).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I was clear enough in the question... I am trying to manage VM snapshots. I already manage code versions separately. The question is for snapshots of virtual machine.